# Overiding abstract method mouse events

Tags: java, methods, handler, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am trying to track mouse movements, but am receiving the following error:  MouseTracker.Handlerclass is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseTracker extends JFrame{
    private JPanel board;
    private JLabel message;

    public MouseTracker(){
        super("Mouse Tracker");
        board = new JPanel();
        board.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        message = new JLabel("No action preformed");
        add(message, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
        board.addMouseListener(handler);
        board.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }

    private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

        public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse was pressed, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
            board.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse was clicked, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
            board.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        public void MouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse was released, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
            board.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        public void MouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse has entered the board, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
            board.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }

        public void MouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse has exited the board, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
            board.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        public void MouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            message.setText(String.format("The mouse was dragged, the current coordinates are: %d,%d", e.getX(), e.getY()));
           board.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        MouseTracker run = new MouseTracker();
        run.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        run.setSize(400,400);
        run.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods in the interface (and in Java as a general rule) start with a lowercase letter. Java is case sensitive, so you get a non-implemented error for your `MouseExited` method.

Comment: look at the method name `mouseExited` and your methods... `MouseExited` see the difference?

Comment: @nbhuiya Well you need to implement that method because of `MouseMotionListener`

Comment: @nbhuiya You had an error and it said "Do task X", then you asked for help. People told you "Do task X". That solved your problem. Now you have another error and it says "Do task Y". What do you think people are going to tell you to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MouseListener is:

```
public interface MouseListener extends EventListener {

/**
 * Invoked when the mouse button has been clicked (pressed
 * and released) on a component.
 */
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e);

/**
 * Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.
 */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e);

/**
 * Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.
 */
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e);

/**
 * Invoked when the mouse enters a component.
 */
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e);

/**
 * Invoked when the mouse exits a component.
 */
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e);
```

}

So you got the case wrong in your methods... They should start with lower case.

Comment: This is also why using ```@Override``` is a good idea. It makes your you are _actually_ overriding a method.